# Brahm sutra number for pashvādabhis cha vīśekā

Tags: advaita, upanishads, adi-shankaracharya, brahma-sutras, body

I am trying to identify the brahmsutra chapter and verse number for this verse

> pashvādabhis cha vīśekā

पश्वादभिस च विशेका

I came across this sloka in a lecture so might not have converted into text correctly, it roughly translates to like animals feels hungry for material food similarly the enlighten needs to take food if they wish to keep their body.

Comment: If you saw it on youtube, could you link the video? Also, are you certain it's from the brahma sutras?

Comment: @CDR its from here - https://kripalunidhi.page.link/aJW73atHgAKcC2aw6
video dated 19-09-2000, around time 3:46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the one you are referring too

> Pashvādibhiścāviśeṣāt

पश्वादिभिश्चाविशेषात्

this was an bhashy written by Jagadguru Shankaracharya
for the first 1st chapter 1st quarter 1st verse

> अथातो ब्रह्मजिज्ञासा

https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/brahmasutra_content?language=dv&field_chapter_value=1&field_quarter_value=1&field_nsutra_value=0

Sri Dhanpati also provided similar Commentary for gita 3.33 mentioning the same

https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?htrskd=1&httyn=1&htshg=1&scsh=1&hcrskd=1&scram=1&scanand=1&scjaya=1&scmad=1&scval=1&scms=1&scsri=1&scneel=1&scdhan=1&&language=dv&field_chapter_value=3&field_nsutra_value=33